# Generate wordlist by List of List of character

Tags: python, python-2.7, word-list

I want to generate a wordlist by list of list of character, like:

```py
A=[['a','b','c'],['d'],['e','f']]
```

where `a[0]` stores all possible character at first place, `a[1]` stores all possible character at second place and so on. All possible words generated by list 'A' will be:

```
ade
adf
bde
bdf
cde
cdf
```

I am generating this list by:

```py
for i in a[0]:
    for j in a[1]:
        for k in a[2]:
            print i+j+k
```

This code works fine for fixed length of `list(i.e. len(A))`. I want to write a generalize code which can generate wordlist by list of any size.

Comment: If question is not clear:
I want to pass list of different length like:
A=[['w','x','y'],['z']]  OR 
A=[['a','b'],['d','e'],['k'],['l','m']]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> characters = [['a','b','c'],['d'],['e','f']]
>>> [''.join(item) for item in product(*characters)]
['ade', 'adf', 'bde', 'bdf', 'cde', 'cdf']
```

This will work irrespective of the lengths of the sublists, as the `product` method computes a Cartesian product of the elements of sublist. Also, since we are passing the sublists with python `*characters` magic, we can pass any number of sublist.

Comment: apologies for the mistaken edit.